# ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: ï

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to download a json file from a url and convert it to a json object using following code which throws an exception:

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetString((Invoke-WebRequest $url).Content) | 
    ConvertFrom-Json
```

It throws:

> ```
> ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: ï
> ```

It throws the same exception if I use `Unicode` or `UTF8`.

But if I download the file using browser and look for the character in the file, there is no such character in the file. Also if you try to convert the saved file to json object, it works properly:

```
Get-Content $localFilePath | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Why do I receive this exception?
How can I get the file content without saving to a file and pass to `ConvertFrom-Json` without problem?

Comment: You could use Invoke-RestMethod that will give you just the Rest content from the site you are trying to get data from.  No headers.

Comment: @thomschumacher It's not about headers. `(Invoke-WebRequest $url).Content` doesn't include headers. It's just content. Even if you use `Invoke-RestMethod` you receive the same exception. The problem is because of BOM at beginning of the content.

Comment: I was going to say that you should be able to use `[System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new($true).GetString((Invoke-WebRequest $url).Content)`, but... how exactly are you calling `Invoke-WebRequest` and getting a byte array in `Content`?  `Invoke-WebReqest` returns a `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject`. 
 `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject.Content` is of type `string`, and `System.Text.Encoding.GetString()` doesn't have a `string` overload?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  The doc says that `Invoke-WebRequest` always returns an `HtmlWebResponseObject`, but that's not true.  It can also return a `WebResponseObject`.

Comment: @BaconBits `(Invoke-WebRequest $url).Content` is a byte array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the problem, you can use:

```
[System.Net.WebClient]::new().DownloadString($url) | ConvertFrom-Json
```

The problem is because of existence of [BOM(U+FEFF byte order mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character at beginning of a file encoded with UTF8. If you get the content of the file from url this way:

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetString((Invoke-WebRequest $url).Content)
```

You will see `ï»¿` at beginning of the file while when saving it using browser, you can not see such sequence.